# Why make this activity does not show my layout?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have the following code

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
```

public class Happy_HourActivity extends SherlockActivity{

```
private ListView listaHP;
private Bundle bundle;
private List<HappyHourModel> listaHpModelResponse; 
private HappyHourAdapter adapterHappyHour;

public void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_happy__hour);
    setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light_DarkActionBar);
    setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Happy Hour");       
    listaHP = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_happy);
    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
```

and is called from an activity called "descriptionActivity" follows.

```
case R.id.happy:
        intent = new Intent(DescriptionActivity.this, Happy_HourActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("_id", _bundle.getString("_id"));
        intent.putExtra("_name", _bundle.getString("_name"));
        startActivity(intent);
    break;
```

layout:

[image]

but this is what show

[image]

Comment: You did not populate your ListView. It's empty.

Comment: @Raghunandan its in `OnCreate()` (notice the spelling of the method) :)

Comment: @codeMagic i noticed the spelling hence i commented but i failed to notice setContentView. was doing something else in between

Comment: @Raghunandan Ah, I wondered if that's what you were doing :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method is wrong for what you want and probably never called

```
public void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
```

it should be

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
```

Small "o". If you would have had the `@Override` annotation there then your IDE probably would have yelled at you making it easier to diagnose before running.

Comment: True that, that happened because erase all contents of that class and when I did write that function poorly, thanks for your help, it worked